# Prevent css transition when angular 4 component load

Tags: css, angular, css-transitions

I have a big problem with css transitions and angular 4.
Actually, I use an external library which provides an input counter (that's my library, so I know no more style is applied to the wrapped input), but on the application I have the following style for the inputs:

```sass
input {
    &[type="text"],
    &[type="password"],
    &[type="email"] {
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid $grey-color;
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
        outline: none;
        width: 100%;
        transition-property: all;
        transition-duration: 300ms;
        font-size: inherit;
    }
}
```

And in the html template:

```html
<input-counter 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="Name" 
    [maxlength]="nameMaxLength"
    [(ngModel)]="name">
</input-counter>
```

**`<input-counter>`** component template:

```html
<style>
  .input-counter-group {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }

  .input-counter-group span {
    color: #b0b0b0;
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  .input-counter-group .text-input-counter {
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 10px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -13px;
  }
</style>
<div class="input-counter-group">
  <input 
    [id]="id" 
    [type]="type"
    [ngClass]="className" 
    [name]="name" 
    [placeholder]="placeholder" 
    [maxlength]="maxlength" 
    [disabled]="disabled" 
    [pattern]="pattern" 
    [required]="required" 
    [readonly]="readonly"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    (focus)="onFocus()" 
    (blur)="onBlur()">
  <span *ngIf="enabled" class="text-input-counter">
    <span *ngIf="displayMinLength()">{{ minlength }} characters at least required: </span>{{ counter }}<span *ngIf="displayMaxLength()">/{{ maxlength }}</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

The problem is when  component is loaded, a css transition is applied to the input, like if the input was "initialized" to the css properties I defined for inputs:

[image]

This animation appears when the component **`<input-counter>`** is displayed, whereas the only animation which should happens is the border color changes when the input is hovered.

Thanks!

**EDIT: the origin of the problem was the plugin codemirror which was loaded with `ngIf`, and applied under the hood a style to my input (itself loaded from another component!), but with css transitions it did the rendering above, so I display it with `[hidden]` and all is ok.**

Comment: what is your goal with that css transition? When it need to be applied if not on load?

Comment: That's not the desired css transition, it's because of the `transition-property: all` it's happening, but the only transition I want to applied is to change the border color on a focused input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angular's animation system](https://angular.io/guide/animations) to get what you are looking for.

Create an animation trigger for your input-counter component, attach it to whichever tag you need to animate in your template and change the trigger's state when you need the transition to happen.

Comment: Thank's I'll take a look!